# In ggplot2/geom_density, how to fill densiyt area with differenc colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

In ggplot2/geom_density, i want to fill the  area of wt >4 with 'YELLOW', but it's failed (some area not in >4 ,the fill color is yellow too. as attached image). Someon can help ? Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x=wt))+
  geom_density(aes(fill=if_else(wt<4,'red','yellow')))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Density graphs show a distribution and so add tails.  This makes it looks like the area below 4 is yellow.  How about using a histogram, that doesn't add them?

For comparison,

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x=wt)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=if_else(wt < 4,'darkred','blue')), bins = 50) +
  geom_density(aes(fill=if_else(wt < 4,'red','yellow')), alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_colour_identity() +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]